# Linq 2 SQL left Join with mono

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, mono

I cant get the fallowing request working in Mono:
Without joins it would work.
when I only select t1 it also works, but I cant select something from both tables.
I think I want a left join, where I always have entries in t1 and IF the NameOfFile matches FileName then I want to have the tables joined.

Extra Question: When is my query executed? When I run the foreach loop?

```
var result = (
            from t1 in db.Table1 
            join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.FileName equals t2.NameOfFile
            into joinDep                
            from t3 in joinDep.DefaultIfEmpty () 
            select new 
            {
            Time = t1.WriteTime,
            Name = t2.NameOfFile

            }
        )
        .OrderByDescending (c => c.Time.Date)
        .Take (10);
foreach (var entry in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine (entry.Name );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var query = from t1 in db.Table1 
            join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.FileName equals t2.NameOfFile into gj
            from joinDep in gj.DefaultIfEmpty ()
            select new 
            {
               Time = t1.WriteTime,
               Name = joinDep.NameOfFile
            };

var result = query.OrderByDescending (c => c.Time.Date)
                .Take (10);
```

Yes. `Take` uses deferred execution.

Comment: I suppose this is the answer to my extra question?

Comment: @JoergWeissbecker I answered to your main question too.

Comment: I cant find joinDep ... I think I copy pasted something wrong

Comment: This works, but when I use the .OrderByDescending (c => c.Time.Date) line, i got an exception

Comment: Show exception. Has `t1.WriteTime` property `Date`?

Comment: Which exception have you got?

Comment: ArgumentException : New
at DbLinq.Vendor.Implementation.SqlProvider.GetLiteral ....

Comment: See edited answer. You mast seriously examine linq syntax either query and expression.

Comment: ok, doesn't matter anymore I just leave the orderby. that definitely did not work but the rest helped. thank you!